# Drawing multiple parallel lines with set distance within polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, archaeology, parallel

I need to draw a series of parallel lines, within a polygon (See example below). Previously I have used MapInfo for this (Easy to draw a grid and delete the horisontal lines), but my workplace is transitioning over to QGIS.

How do I do this in QGIS?

I have seen a few guides that does not quite fit what we need and which, to be honest, seemed fairly hard to follow for people with no formal training in using GIS software.

[image]

The purpose is for digging trenches during archaeological trial excavations prior to development projects, where a north-south trench is dug for every 15 meters.

Comment: Do you need the lines just as an illustration, then you can use BERAs answer below, or do you need to e.g. upload the lines in a GPS to follow them in the terrain?

Comment: I need to be able to export them in .dxf, so that can be uploaded in the excavators GPS and/or our handheld GPS-system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you dont need the lines as a separate layer, you can just set a line pattern fill:

[image]

If you need the lines as a layer:

1. Create a line grid with 15 m spacing
2. Extract vertical lines with the expression `main_angle($geometry) IN(0, 180)`
3. Clip grid with input polygons

[image]

Comment: Yes but it is a bit tricky to chose it so it it fits within the extent (or you get an error), but doesnt create any lines